# product with multiple values

Tags: wordpress

I want to create a product with multiple values, but without a selling option (like a add to cart option). I'm creating a online catalogue, but i have one product with multiple options and thus multiple prices. Is there any possible way to create something like this in Wordpress?

This is what i intend to create: https://www.snellermedia.nl/tennisdoek
Here you can select 4 options and then you get your price for your selection.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes there is. Please avoid plain yes/no questions. If you have an actual, programming related question feel free to post it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i will try next time. But could you help me this time and give me a push in the right direction? That would be very welcome.